# How to clear the contents(tabledata) in a table using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a table inside a `<div>`, binding data using Knockout(ko). I want to clear the data using button click. I found so many examples like empty(), remove(), detach(), which removes entire table, but I want to remove only the text content in table data(Td) on button click.

```
   <div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top: 3px;" id="empTab">
       <table class="table table-bordered">
           <tbody data-bind="foreach: EmployeesModel">
               <tr id="EmployeeRefID" style="background-color: gainsboro">
                   <td>PSA ID</td>
                   <td><span data-bind="text: EmployeeRefID"></span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr id="FirstName">
                   <td>First Name</td>
                   <td><span data-bind="text: FirstName"></span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr id="LastName">
                   <td>Last Name</td>
                   <td><span data-bind="text: LastName"></span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr id="Email">
                   <td>Email</td>
                   <td><span data-bind="text: Email"></span></td>
               </tr>
           <tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('#empTab td:first-child').text('');
```

for all second tds:

```
$('#empTab td:nth-child(2)').text('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#yourButton").click(function(){
       $("#empTab").find("td").text("");
   });
});
```

Comment: Please put your code in jsfiddle. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @Milind Anantwar's answer:

```
<button id="btnClear" data-bind="click: clearData()">Clear</button>


function clearData() {
  $('#empTab td:nth-child(2)').text('');
}
```